# Bundle module that only exports module in node

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, commonjs, emscripten, rollupjs

I'm trying to bundle a Emscripten build with rollup.js. Emscripten is generating a file that will only export with `module.exports` when using a node environment to prevent errors when using the file directly in the browser. Here is a minimal example:

```js
// emscripten-module.js
var Module = typeof Module != "undefined" ? Module : {};
var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE = typeof process == "object" && typeof process.versions == "object" && typeof process.versions.node == "string";
if (ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE) {
    {
        module["exports"] = Module;
    }
}
// ...
```

Rollup.js is bundling this into a UMD build using `@rollup/plugin-commonjs`:

```js
// bundle.js
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (global = typeof globalThis !== 'undefined' ? globalThis : global || self, global.myPackage = factory());
})(this, (function () { 'use strict';

    var wasm = {exports: {}};

    (function (module) {
        // emscripten-module.js code goes here
    } (wasm));

    var Module = wasm.exports;

    var index = {
        module: Module,
    };

    return index;

}));
```

When using this bundle in a browser and not in a node context `window.myPackage.module` will actually always be empty because of the `if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE)` condition. Is there a way to get around this? Can I just tell rollup to expose a certain variable of a module (=file), `Module` in this case? Am I missing an option for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem by just adding another `module.exports` statement at the end of `emscripten-module.js`. Either by hand or with a little rollup plugin:

```js
const targets = [
    '/emscripten-module.js',
];

function appendModuleExports(string) {
    return `${string}
module.exports = Module;`;
}

export default function addModuleExports() {
    return {
        name: 'add-module-exports',
        transform(source, id) {
            if (!targets.some(s => id.endsWith(s))) {
                return;
            }
            return {
                code: appendModuleExports(source),
                map: null,
            };
        },
    };
};
```

Make sure to set this plugin before the `commonjs()` plugin.